# Getting the text from programatically opening the android keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

I have opened the keyboard using this:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

but I don't know how to get the text which has been inputted through the keyboard. Any help?

Comment: Why do you need to `SHOW_IMPLICIT`? Any edittext or textfield to receive the text? otherwise as far as I know there will be noway to receive those text.

Comment: view.getText() doesnt it work?

Comment: view doesn't have that method @Tarun
user2652394, Shall I just create a temporary EditText which isn't shown to get the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input method framework is based upon the idea of an input connection.  The framework instantiates one between the keyboard and the EditText.  If you want to accept text from the keyboard you need to implement that side of the interface yourself, then get the framework to use your interface as the other half of the input session.  This is really, really non-trivial and if you do it wrong specialized keyboards like Swype, Swiftkey, etc will not work correctly.  I wouldn't suggest doing it without a very good reason.

If you just want them to type into an existing edit text, focus that view instead.  That way the input connection will be set to that view and everything will be done for you.